# Android change datetime

Tags: java, android, json, calendar

i want to change datetime type for example dd.MM.yyyy i parsed json and i want to change datetime format. I wrote some code and able to change datetime format but time is always same,

for example 2.3.2014 this is a my code

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

    String DateTimeTxt = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate);
    DateTimeTxt = date;

    DateTime.setText(DateTimeTxt);
```

what is a problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried with your code. It is ok for date format convertion, I think.

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

    String DateTimeTxt = "2.3.2014";
    DateTimeTxt = date;

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date)).setText(DateTimeTxt);
```

The output is : **03.02.2014**

So I think your problem is to get actual data on below line of your code :

`String DateTimeTxt = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate);`

Print this string and identify what you want and what you get.

Comment: thank you but i loged this String  and also  itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate).please look at picture : (http://postimg.org/image/ygjgi6ym1/)  Format Date Time always 03.02.2014

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
   Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = df.parse(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate));

        DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        DateTime.setText(df1.format(date));
```

You are formatting the current date but not the date you received from JSON.

Comment: i c changed but i have illegalArgumentExceptin

Comment: "itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate)" what is the output of this? please print a log and check.

Comment: i loged  itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate) and it is a right same as a json but when i try to change format i can only show same date. all news have a same time

Comment: Why there is letter 'T' between date and time? remove it and try above code. i have edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar ctaq = Calendar.getInstance();
        ctaq.setTimeInMillis(ctaq.getTimeInMillis());
        SimpleDateFormat dfaq = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
        String datetimestr = dfaq.format(ctaq.getTime());
```

Use this for change the format.Its working for me

Comment: i changed code but i can format datetime but all datetime is same .i run project and all items' datetime is similar 2.3.2014

Answer (score 0):

Just like time you can change you date in different format
**[See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458797/get-current-time-on-the-device-when-server-has-gmt/21459143#21459143)**